# PHP print a vaue in row and column

Tags: php, arrays, printing, expression

I am querying my database using this code (showing part of code):

In back end I use ExpressionEngine, Matrix, Cartthrob and DataGrab

I am using MySQL and PHP to write the code

```
foreach($retailprices->result_array() as $row)
{
print_r($row);
```

This is the result:

```
Array ( [row_order] => 1 [col_id_3] => 3.500 ) 
Array ( [row_order] => 2 [col_id_3] => 12.95 ) 
Array ( [row_order] => 3 [col_id_3] => 37.45 )
```

I want to extract 3.500, 12.95 and 37.45 to an array

Then I want to print them one by one
using array.  Output should look like:

```
3.500
12.95
37.45
```

Please some one guide me to solve this issue.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please add the code where you actually do the query. Or just state what database system and API you are using (MySQL?, MSSQL?).

Comment: try this foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
print " $val\n";
}     this is just for printing

Comment: Dear Satya.  Thanks for comments.  I edit the post. Please check it and help me.

Comment: Dear Mark Garcia,  I edited the post.  I am using MySQL with PHP.  Please help me tosolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($row as $out) 
{
print "$out"."<br>";
}
```

This prints the array.

The output will be

```
3.500
12.95
37.45
```

Is this what you are looking for?

**EDIT :**

```
foreach($retailprices->result_array() as $row)
{
 print($row[col_id_3]); // assuming col_id_3 is the column name
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

```
foreach($retailprices->result_array() as $row)
{
 $blah=$row[col_id_3]; 
}

echo $blah[0]; // 3.500
echo $blah[1]; // 12.95
echo $blah[2]; // 37.45
```

Comment: Dear Bhuvan,  I tried your code.  I believe I did not give you a good explanation.  I edited the post. Please check it and help me.  Thanks

Comment: @user1427195 Is `col_id_3` your column name?

Comment: Yes, col_id_3 is column name.  I will test your code and let you know.  Thanks for the answer

Comment: Dear Bhuvan Rikka, Great it works.  I got 3 prices.  Do you know a way to sesperate them and put each prices in an three element array?  This is what I got when I use your code.                                                            3.500
12.95
37.45    Please help.

Comment: @user1427195 `$row` is a multi dimensional array and `$row[col_id_3]` is a one-dimensional array containing 3.500 12.95 37.45. So why again keeping them in a array? `$row[col_id_3]` is already an array

Comment: Sorry I cannot discuss through this system because I have posted only 5 posts. Please continue help as much as you can

Comment: @user1427195 Sure mate, but the thing is your problem is solved coz the values are stored in an array by default. `$row[col_id_3]` is that array

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I want to separate the prices and use them separate occasions. Do you know a way to separate prices? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1427195 Ahh.. you should've said that earlier.. Or i didn't get it :D ..whatever..check the edit

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I will check your code and let you know.

Comment: @user1427195 That will work for sure. If you still have issues,let me know. I'll check that tomorrow. I'm leaving my office now.

Comment: Great it works.  But it did not print out all the parts of the numbers.  Here is the output  3.5
12.
37.  Do you know a way to fix this. Please help. Thanks

Comment: @user1427195 Use `echo floatval($blah)`.. Refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and let you know

Comment: Great now it gave 3.53
12.95
37.45 is there a way to put those prices in different cells in an array and print (like last time) I really appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't make alot of sense for your code.  print "$key ==> $val\n";  has a new line character, yet your output doesn't. Where is the 01 at the start of the line coming from?

**Edit**

```
$array = array();

foreach($retailprices->result_array() as $row)
    $array[] = $row['col_id_3'];

foreach($array as $a)
    echo $a."<br>";
```

Comment: Dear shapeshifter,  You are correct. I changed the code and  I edited the post. Please check it and help me.  Thanks

Comment: Bhuvan has got pretty close.   You probably want to add the result to the array instead of setting the variable $blah each time.  $blah[] = $row[col_id_3];  Then to output foreach($blah as $b) { echo $b."\n" } or "<br>" instead of new line if you are outputting to a web browser.

Comment: Dear shapeshifter,  Thank you very much for your help. In my first post I forgot to tell that I am using Expression engine with Matrix.  I believe matrix create an object of price and it is in one cell.  May be that is why it is hard pull out separate prices.  Do you know a way to change an object to an array and pull out data from array?  Thank you very much.

Comment: I haven't used Matrix or ExpressionEngine before.  Try typecast your object as an array $array = (array) $object;  Or google search "object to assoc array" has plenty of functions that all do multi dimensional  conversions for you.  You should be able to access the properties of the object easily though.  I'd rather work with an object than an array.